# d3Plus and wrapping text

Tags: javascript, d3.js, word-wrap, d3plus

I'm trying to use D3plus to wrap text - i'm starting to understand how it is to make text in a SVG wrap. However, i keep getting errors that are either to do with d3Plus or my code - the documentation with D3 is pretty sparse, so i'm looking to get some assistance on where i have been going wrong. Cheers.

**JS**

```
<script>

var dataPoints = [
    ["Arsenal", -0.0032967741593940836, 0.30399753945657115],
    ["Chelsea", 0.2752159801936051, -0.0389675484210763],
    ["Liverpool", -0.005096951348655329, 0.026678627680541075],
    ["Manchester City", -0.004715381791104284, -0.12338379196523988],
    ["Manchester United", 0.06877966010653305, -0.0850615090351779],
    ["Tottenham", -0.3379518099485709, -0.09933664174939877]
];

var teamData = [
    ["Arsenal", "@arsenal", "world", "cup", "arsenal", "", "@sahil_adhikaari", "win", "@hectorbellerin", "man", "season"],
    ["Chelsea", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],
    ["Liverpool", "l", "m", "m", "o", "p"],
    ["Manchester City", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u"],
    ["Manchester United", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"],
    ["Tottenham", "1", "2", "3 ", "4", "5"]
];

const colours = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(dataPoints)
    .range(["#F8B195", "#F67280", "#C06C84", "#6C5B7B", "#355C7D", "#2A363B"]);

var canvasW = 700;
var canvasH = 600;   
var w = 365;
var h = 365;
var xPadding = 30;
var yPadding = 20;
var padding = 10;
var border = 0.5;
var bordercolor = 'black';

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([xPadding, w - padding])
    .domain([-1, 1]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([h - yPadding, padding])
    .domain([-1, 1]);

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append("svg")
    .attr('width', canvasW)
    .attr('height', canvasH);

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(dataPoints)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 7)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d[1]); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d[2]); })
    .on('click', function(d, i) {
        console.log("click", d[0]);
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
        var result = null;

        if (dataPoints.indexOf(d) >= 0) {
            result = colours(d);
        } else {
            result = "white";
        }
        return result;               
    });

var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(colours.domain())
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 29 + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", canvasW - 184)
    .attr("y", 11)
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", colours);

legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", canvasW - 194)
    .attr("y", 20)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text(function(d) { return d[0];})

var borderPath = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 5)
    .attr("y", 5)
    .attr("height", h)
    .attr("width", w)
    .style("stroke", bordercolor)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke-width", border);

var textBox = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(5,385)");

textBox.append("rect")
    .attr("id", "target")
    .attr("height", 150)
    .attr("width", 529)
    .style("stroke", bordercolor)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke-width", border);

    filter();
    function filter(d) {
    d3.select("body").selectAll(null);
        circles.on("click", filter);
        var filterss = teamData.filter(e => e[0] === d[0])[0];
        var team = filterss.slice(0, 1);
        filterss = filterss.slice(1, filterss.length);
        team = team + ": "
        filterss = filterss.join(", ")
        console.log(team + filterss);

  new d3plus.TextBox()
    .select(textBox.node())
    .data(team + filterss)
    .text( function(d){ return d; })
    .width(textBox.select('rect').attr("width"))
    .fontSize(20)
    .render();
}
```

[image: The Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the line the error is occurring at when importing `d3plus`, you'll see this;

```
 d3.scale.ordinal()
```

That's d3 **version 3** syntax, while it looks like you are using d3 **version 4**.

It looks like you want [this library](https://github.com/d3plus/d3plus-text) for version 4 (and it's specific to text-wrapping).

And here's an example merging the new API with your code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://d3plus.org/js/d3plus-text.v0.9.full.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var dataPoints = [
      ["Arsenal", -0.0032967741593940836, 0.30399753945657115],
      ["Chelsea", 0.2752159801936051, -0.0389675484210763],
      ["Liverpool", -0.005096951348655329, 0.026678627680541075],
      ["Manchester City", -0.004715381791104284, -0.12338379196523988],
      ["Manchester United", 0.06877966010653305, -0.0850615090351779],
      ["Tottenham", -0.3379518099485709, -0.09933664174939877]
    ];

    teamData = [
      ["Arsenal", "@arsenal", "world", "cup", "arsenal", "", "@sahil_adhikaari", "win", "@hectorbellerin", "man", "season"],
      ["Chelsea", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],
      ["Liverpool", "l", "m", "m", "o", "p"],
      ["Manchester City", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u"],
      ["Manchester United", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"],
      ["Tottenham", "1", "2", "3 ", "4", "5"]
    ];

    const colours = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(dataPoints)
      .range(["#F8B195", "#F67280", "#C06C84", "#6C5B7B", "#355C7D", "#2A363B"]);

    var canvasW = 700;
    var canvasH = 600;
    var w = 365;
    var h = 365;
    var xPadding = 30;
    var yPadding = 20;
    var padding = 10;
    var border = 0.5;
    var bordercolor = 'black';

    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([xPadding, w - padding])
      .domain([-1, 1]);

    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([h - yPadding, padding])
      .domain([-1, 1]);

    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append("svg")
      .attr('width', canvasW)
      .attr('height', canvasH);

    var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(dataPoints)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 7)
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return xScale(d[1]);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale(d[2]);
      })
      .on('click', function(d, i) {
        console.log("click", d[0]);
      })
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        var result = null;

        if (dataPoints.indexOf(d) >= 0) {
          result = colours(d);
        } else {
          result = "white";
        }
        return result;
      });

    var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(colours.domain())
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(0," + i * 29 + ")";
      });

    legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", canvasW - 184)
      .attr("y", 11)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", colours);

    legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", canvasW - 194)
      .attr("y", 20)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d[0];
      })

    var borderPath = svg.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 5)
      .attr("y", 5)
      .attr("height", h)
      .attr("width", w)
      .style("stroke", bordercolor)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke-width", border);

    var textBox = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(5,385)");

    textBox.append("rect")
      .attr("id", "target")
      .attr("height", 150)
      .attr("width", 529)
      .style("stroke", bordercolor)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke-width", border);

    circles.on("click", filter);

    filter(["Arsenal"]);

    function filter(d) {
      d3.select("body").selectAll(null);

      var filterss = teamData.filter(e =>e[0] === d[0])[0];
      var team = filterss.slice(0, 1);
      filterss = filterss.slice(1, filterss.length);
      team = team + ": "
      filterss = filterss.join(", ")
      console.log(team + filterss);

      new d3plus.TextBox()
        .select(textBox.node())
        .data([team + filterss])
        .text(function(d) {
          return d;
        })
        .width(textBox.select('rect').attr("width"))
        .fontSize(20)
        .render();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: After some digging, d3Plus doesn't exist (from what i can see)... Do you have any other simple suggestions for text wrapping?

Comment: Yes, i've tried the. But i get the error of `d3plus.textBox is not a contructor`

Comment: @FeelingLikeAJabroni, added a running code snippet for how you might use that library.

Comment: Thanks for that, i'll play around with it now... But why would you comment out important code in order for it to work?

Comment: @FeelingLikeAJabroni, I commented it out because your code sample was incomplete and those variables are not defined.  Besides, my sample code should be enough to get you going just replace my "data" with `team + filterss`

Comment: Hmm, i see. I'm getting a new error now (see updated code and attached image). The errors are now uncaught type errors? Sorry for what seems basic, i'm new to Javascript and D3 - i'm learning as i go.

Comment: I've been pulling out my hair because of this... Such simple changes.. How did you figure this out?

Comment: Very useful. I actually came for an example on how `d3plus` interacts with `d3`. The important part for me was `new d3plus.TextBox().select(/* this is where the text goes */). ...` and that `.render()` actually creates (appends) the text in the selection.